# reference from errors in Xcode

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

I'm trying to add google analytics to my iOS game (using unity) but I get 27 errors that read "_buildCampaignParametersDictionary, referenced from" and at the end it says "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64".

I have linked the correct libraries in Xcode, updated the plugin, updated Unity and cleaned the project already. Nothing works. Does anyone know how to fix these errors and let the game be built to the iPhone?

```
#include "il2cpp-config.h"

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#include <alloca.h>
#else
# include <malloc.h>
#endif

#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <assert.h>

//AdvertiserOptInAttribute
struct AdvertiserOptInAttribute_t2511370351;
//AppViewHitBuilder
struct AppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662;
//System.String
struct String_t;
//EventHitBuilder
struct EventHitBuilder_t1002727074;
//ExceptionHitBuilder
struct ExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103;
//Field
struct Field_t67875034;
//Fields
struct Fields_t2104126169;
//GAIHandler
struct GAIHandler_t2440579483;
//System.Object
struct Il2CppObject;
//HitBuilder`1<AppViewHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t2647405828;
//HitBuilder`1<System.Object>
struct HitBuilder_1_t538047241;
//HitBuilder`1<EventHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t1664925240;
//TransactionHitBuilder
struct TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294;
//HitBuilder`1<TransactionHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t3433902460;
//ItemHitBuilder
struct ItemHitBuilder_t4057071643;
//HitBuilder`1<ItemHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t424302513;
//HitBuilder`1<ExceptionHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t3209252269;
//SocialHitBuilder
struct SocialHitBuilder_t125430773;
//HitBuilder`1<SocialHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t787628939;
//TimingHitBuilder
struct TimingHitBuilder_t471798930;
//HitBuilder`1<TimingHitBuilder>
struct HitBuilder_1_t1133997096;
//GoogleAnalyticsAndroidV4
struct GoogleAnalyticsAndroidV4_t1312358048;
//GoogleAnalyticsiOSV3
struct GoogleAnalyticsiOSV3_t3357933149;
//GoogleAnalyticsMPV3
struct GoogleAnalyticsMPV3_t3848265261;
//GoogleAnalyticsV4
struct GoogleAnalyticsV4_t1063221387;
//RangedTooltipAttribute
struct RangedTooltipAttribute_t2732834528;
//TooltipAttribute
struct TooltipAttribute_t1863881209;

#include "class-internals.h"
#include "codegen/il2cpp-codegen.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Array1146569071.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_U3CModuleU3E86524790.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_U3CModuleU3E86524790MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_AdvertiserOptInAttri2511370351.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_AdvertiserOptInAttri2511370351MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Void2863195528.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_PropertyAttribute3531521085MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_AppViewHitBuilder1985207662.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_AppViewHitBuilder1985207662MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen2647405828MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_String7231557.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_String7231557MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Debug4195163081MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Boolean476798718.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Object4170816371.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_EventHitBuilder1002727074.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_EventHitBuilder1002727074MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen1664925240MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Int641153838595.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_ExceptionHitBuilder2547054103.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_ExceptionHitBuilder2547054103MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen3209252269MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_Field67875034.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_Field67875034MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Object4170816371MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_Fields2104126169.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_Fields2104126169MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GAIHandler2440579483.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GAIHandler2440579483MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Int321153838500.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_IntPtr4010401971.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen2647405828.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen1664925240.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Double3868226565.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TransactionHitBuilde2771704294.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TransactionHitBuilde2771704294MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen3433902460.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_ItemHitBuilder4057071643.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_ItemHitBuilder4057071643MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen424302513.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen3209252269.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_SocialHitBuilder125430773.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_SocialHitBuilder125430773MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen787628939.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TimingHitBuilder471798930.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TimingHitBuilder471798930MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen1133997096.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsAndro1312358048.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsAndro1312358048MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsiOSV33357933149.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsiOSV33357933149MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsV4_Deb632311282.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsMPV33848265261.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsMPV33848265261MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsV41063221387.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsV41063221387MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_MonoBehaviour667441552MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Application_LogCallback2984951347MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Application2856536070MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_LogType4286006228.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Application_LogCallback2984951347.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_StackTraceUtility4217621253MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Object3071478659MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "UnityEngine_UnityEngine_Object3071478659.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_GoogleAnalyticsV4_Deb632311282MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen424302513MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_RangedTooltipAttribu2732834528.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_RangedTooltipAttribu2732834528MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "mscorlib_System_Single4291918972.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen787628939MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen1133997096MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TooltipAttribute1863881209.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_TooltipAttribute1863881209MethodDeclarations.h"
#include "AssemblyU2DCSharpU2Dfirstpass_HitBuilder_1_gen3433902460MethodDeclarations.h"

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<System.Object>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, HitBuilder_1_t538047241 * p0, const MethodInfo* method);
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t538047241 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)
//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<AppViewHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m1624150402(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t2647405828 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<EventHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m2045123894(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t1664925240 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<TransactionHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m409123066(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t3433902460 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<ItemHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisItemHitBuilder_t4057071643_m3723849355(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t424302513 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<ExceptionHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m116209451(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t3209252269 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<SocialHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m3459587557(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t787628939 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)

//System.Void GAIHandler::_buildCampaignParametersDictionary<TimingHitBuilder>(HitBuilder`1<!!0>)
#define GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTimingHitBuilder_t471798930_m3196376578(__this, p0, method) ((  void (*) (GAIHandler_t2440579483 *, HitBuilder_1_t1133997096 *, const MethodInfo*))GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisIl2CppObject_m3469309170_gshared)(__this, p0, method)
#ifdef __clang__
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Winvalid-offsetof"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
#endifFields*)Fields_t2104126169_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var->static_fields)->set_EVENT_CATEGORY_28(L_28);
    Field_t67875034 * L_29 = (Field_t67875034 *)il2cpp_codegen_object_new(Field_t67875034_il2cpp_TypeInfo_var);
    Field__ctor_m2116843141(L_29, _stringLiteral39746, /*hidden argument*/NULL);

//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendAppView(AppViewHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m4053593726_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m3182742534_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m1624150402_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendAppView_m3263218325_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendAppView_m3263218325 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, AppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendAppView_m3263218325_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    AppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662 * L_0 = ___builder0;
    GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m1624150402(__this, L_2, /*hidden argument*/GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisAppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662_m1624150402_MethodInfo_var);
    AppViewHitBuilder_t1985207662 * L_3 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_3);
    String_t* L_4 = AppViewHitBuilder_GetScreenName_m840944343(L_3, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    GAIHandler_sendAppView_m2176131378(NULL /*static, unused*/, L_4, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    return;
}
}
//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendEvent(EventHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m2204076338_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m3378587834_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m2045123894_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendEvent_m968372397_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendEvent_m968372397 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendEvent_m968372397_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * L_0 = ___builder0;
    GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m2045123894(__this, L_2, /*hidden argument*/GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisEventHitBuilder_t1002727074_m2045123894_MethodInfo_var);
    EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * L_3 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_3);
    String_t* L_4 = EventHitBuilder_GetEventCategory_m375089998(L_3, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * L_5 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_5);
    String_t* L_6 = EventHitBuilder_GetEventAction_m2968561222(L_5, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * L_7 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_7);
    String_t* L_8 = EventHitBuilder_GetEventLabel_m2164191366(L_7, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    EventHitBuilder_t1002727074 * L_9 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_9);
    int64_t L_10 = EventHitBuilder_GetEventValue_m3853167127(L_9, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    GAIHandler_sendEvent_m1794309986(NULL /*static, unused*/, L_4, L_6, L_8, L_10, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    return;
}
}
//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendTransaction(TransactionHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m2961324022_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m3403682174_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m409123066_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendTransaction_m1617298085_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendTransaction_m1617298085 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendTransaction_m1617298085_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_0 = ___builder0;
    GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m409123066(__this, L_2, /*hidden argument*/GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294_m409123066_MethodInfo_var);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_3 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_3);
    String_t* L_4 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetTransactionID_m1022718035(L_3, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_5 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_5);
    String_t* L_6 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetAffiliation_m2381645642(L_5, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_7 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_7);
    double L_8 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetRevenue_m3622763958(L_7, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_9 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_9);
    double L_10 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetTax_m2928772613(L_9, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_11 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_11);
    double L_12 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetShipping_m3645003446(L_11, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    TransactionHitBuilder_t2771704294 * L_13 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_13);
    String_t* L_14 = TransactionHitBuilder_GetCurrencyCode_m1428989670(L_13, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    GAIHandler_sendTransaction_m2437246118(NULL /*static, unused*/, L_4, L_6, L_8, L_10, L_12, L_14, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    return;
}
}
//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendException(ExceptionHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m2644002087_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m3274629295_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m116209451_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendException_m57579075_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendException_m57579075 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, ExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendException_m57579075_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    ExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103 * L_0 = ___builder0;
GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m116209451(__this, L_2, /*hidden argument*/GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103_m116209451_MethodInfo_var);
    ExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103 * L_3 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_3);
    String_t* L_4 = ExceptionHitBuilder_GetExceptionDescription_m1708188068(L_3, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    ExceptionHitBuilder_t2547054103 * L_5 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_5);
    bool L_6 = ExceptionHitBuilder_IsFatal_m3864057332(L_5, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    GAIHandler_sendException_m2056688628(NULL /*static, unused*/, L_4, L_6, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    return;
}
}
//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendSocial(SocialHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m4092146025_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m1847296737_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m3459587557_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendSocial_m59438577_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendSocial_m59438577 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, SocialHitBuilder_t125430773 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendSocial_m59438577_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    SocialHitBuilder_t125430773 * L_0 = ___builder0;

GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m3459587557(__this, L_2, /*hidden argument*/GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisSocialHitBuilder_t125430773_m3459587557_MethodInfo_var);
    SocialHitBuilder_t125430773 * L_3 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_3);
    String_t* L_4 = SocialHitBuilder_GetSocialNetwork_m3403622584(L_3, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    SocialHitBuilder_t125430773 * L_5 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_5);
    String_t* L_6 = SocialHitBuilder_GetSocialAction_m2959141774(L_5, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    SocialHitBuilder_t125430773 * L_7 = ___builder0;
    NullCheck(L_7);
    String_t* L_8 = SocialHitBuilder_GetSocialTarget_m4173362217(L_7, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    GAIHandler_sendSocial_m4293817589(NULL /*static, unused*/, L_4, L_6, L_8, /*hidden argument*/NULL);
    return;
}
}
//System.Void GAIHandler::_sendTiming(TimingHitBuilder)
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomMetricsDictionary_TisTimingHitBuilder_t471798930_m3828935046_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCustomDimensionsDictionary_TisTimingHitBuilder_t471798930_m1584085758_MethodInfo_var;
extern const MethodInfo* GAIHandler__buildCampaignParametersDictionary_TisTimingHitBuilder_t471798930_m3196376578_MethodInfo_var;
extern const uint32_t GAIHandler__sendTiming_m3263175825_MetadataUsageId;
extern "C"  void GAIHandler__sendTiming_m3263175825 (GAIHandler_t2440579483 * __this, TimingHitBuilder_t471798930 * ___builder0, const MethodInfo* method)
{
static bool s_Il2CppMethodIntialized;
if (!s_Il2CppMethodIntialized)
{
    il2cpp_codegen_initialize_method (GAIHandler__sendTiming_m3263175825_MetadataUsageId);
    s_Il2CppMethodIntialized = true;
}
{
    TimingHitBuilder_t471798930 * L_0 = ___builder0;
    }
extern "C" void DEFAULT_CALL buildCampaignParametersDictionary(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*);
//System.Void GAIHandler::buildCampaignParametersDictionary(System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String)
extern "C"  void GAIHandler_buildCampaignParametersDictionary_m2862549954 (Il2CppObject * __this /* static, unused */, String_t* ___source0, String_t* ___medium1, String_t* ___name2, String_t* ___content3, String_t* ___keyword4, const MethodInfo* method)
{
typedef void (DEFAULT_CALL *PInvokeFunc) (char*, char*, char*, char*, char*);

// Marshaling of parameter '___source0' to native representation
char* ____source0_marshaled = NULL;
____source0_marshaled = il2cpp_codegen_marshal_string(___source0);

// Marshaling of parameter '___medium1' to native representation
char* ____medium1_marshaled = NULL;
____medium1_marshaled = il2cpp_codegen_marshal_string(___medium1);

// Marshaling of parameter '___name2' to native representation
char* ____name2_marshaled = NULL;
____name2_marshaled = il2cpp_codegen_marshal_string(___name2);

// Marshaling of parameter '___content3' to native representation
char* ____content3_marshaled = NULL;
____content3_marshaled = il2cpp_codegen_marshal_string(___content3);

// Marshaling of parameter '___keyword4' to native representation
char* ____keyword4_marshaled = NULL;
____keyword4_marshaled = il2cpp_codegen_marshal_string(___keyword4);

// Native function invocation
reinterpret_cast<PInvokeFunc>(buildCampaignParametersDictionary)(____source0_marshaled, ____medium1_marshaled, ____name2_marshaled, ____content3_marshaled, ____keyword4_marshaled);

// Marshaling cleanup of parameter '___source0' native representation
il2cpp_codegen_marshal_free(____source0_marshaled);
____source0_marshaled = NULL;

// Marshaling cleanup of parameter '___medium1' native representation
il2cpp_codegen_marshal_free(____medium1_marshaled);
____medium1_marshaled = NULL;

// Marshaling cleanup of parameter '___name2' native representation
il2cpp_codegen_marshal_free(____name2_marshaled);
____name2_marshaled = NULL;

// Marshaling cleanup of parameter '___content3' native representation
il2cpp_codegen_marshal_free(____content3_marshaled);
____content3_marshaled = NULL;

// Marshaling cleanup of parameter '___keyword4' native representation
il2cpp_codegen_marshal_free(____keyword4_marshaled);
____keyword4_marshaled = NULL;
}
```

Comment: show the source code, surprisingly we are wizards :)

Comment: trying to figure out how to post it because it keeps saying its too long

Comment: try posting only the strictly necessary code, not the whole project

Comment: "I have linked the correct libraries in Xcode, and cleaned the project already." What libraries did you link? Also, what's your Unity version?

Comment: @ddb I have edited the question to now include a sample of the source code

Comment: @Programmer I linked "CoreData.framework" "AdSupport.framework" "SystemConfiguration.framework" "libz.tbd" and "libsqlite3.0.tbd". Unity version 5.4.2f2

Comment: It should be "libz.dylib" and "libsqlite3.dylib" with  "CoreData.framework" "AdSupport.framework"  and "SystemConfiguration.framework". Fix the first two. if the problem is still there, I suggest you update Unity to 5.6 then use the latest the latest version from [here](https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-plugin-for-unity).

Comment: @Programmer Still didn't work. I fixed the first two then I updated Unity and the google analytics. Getting the same errors. But with the errors at the bottom it says "symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64"

Comment: Now you are getting new error? If so, update your question with that error.

Comment: @Programmer updated my question

Comment: Add `Security.framework` and also set *Build For Active Architectures* to *YES* and see what happens. If *Build For Active Architectures* is already set to *YES*, change it to *NO*

Comment: Added the framework. Changed the Build For Active Architectures to YES and No, both times they failed and gave me the same error

Comment: From Unity Editor, go to Help-->Report a Bug. Tell Unity your project is not building then submit the project. Wait to hear from them. I also assume that you are using the latest version Xcode.